# spring boot set spring.profiles.active from external application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to set the active profile from a yml (without setting it via ENV variables or command line options)?

Within the source I have `src/main/resources/application.yml`:

```
spring.profiles.default: development

spring:
    profiles: production
    datasource:
        # sensible info reside in application.yml next to the final jar
        url: dummy
        password: dummy
        username: dummy
  ...
```

now I package a [executable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) fat jar `myapp.jar`.
I upload the file to a server and put a file `application.yml` next to it with contents:

```
spring.profiles.active: production

spring:
    profiles: production
    datasource:
        # sensible info reside in application.yml next to the final jar
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
        password: the_production_password
        username: the_production_username
```

running it via `./myapp.jar` I would expect the **production** profile to be activated. But it is not:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: development
```

I know that spring is capable of reading the external `application.yml`, because when activating the profile using the command line option `--spring.profiles.active=production`, I get the overridden values of the file and the db connection is fine.

However, I want to configure the active profile not from command line or environment variables. Isn't this possible?

Comment: it is possible, sure, think of spring cloud config, you have your config from a git repo, but i don't think there is a out of the box solution..

Comment: instead of `spring.profiles.active: production` try `spring.profiles.default: production`. Check this post https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5998